# Как подключить джойстик к игроку в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

СКРИПТ ДЖОСТИКА

```
1.using UnityEngine;
2.using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
3.
4.public class Joystick : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
5.{
6.    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
7    {
8       transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
9       transform.localPosition = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(transform.localPosition, 45f);
10  }
11

    12  public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    13 {
    14    transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    15 }

16}
```

Я написал код джойстика и стал писать код игрока. Я хотел чтобы, мой игрок управлялся джойстиком и клавиатурой, и двигался с помощью джойстика и клавиатуры. Но что-то пошло не так и у меня выдало ошибку на этой строке:

`moveInput = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal, joystick.Vertical);`

Ошибка:

> Assets\Player.cs(30,46): error CS1061: 'Joystick' does not contain a
> definition for 'Horizontal' and no accessible extension method
> 'Horizontal' accepting a first argument of type 'Joystick' could be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

---

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ControlType controlType;
    public Joystick joystick;
    public float speed;


 public enum ControlType{PC, Android}

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Vector2 moveInput;
private Vector2 moveVelocity;
```

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

Вы написали (скачали) класс `Joystick`, в котором ничего не сказано про методы/свойства/поля с именами `Horizontal` и `Vertical`.

Если просто нужен джойстик и клавиатура используйте `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")` и `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` вместо ваших: `joystick.Horizontal, joystick.Vertical`

Comment: я хочу чтобы у меня придвижении джостика двигался персонаж как на плэйстейшен а если я напишу эту команду то я буду управлять только через клавиатуру

Comment: @Denti **Edit > Project Settings > Input** для настройки осей, если вас не устраивает их поведение по умолчанию.